# azure resource manager servicebus provider?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-resource-manager

Is there such a thing as a ServiceBus provider? As part of my application I would like to include a SB namespace, topic and subscriptions. Is the expectation that you deploy the website(s) using ARM, and use the service interface for scripting the other supporting features?

Answer (score 7):

There is a Service Bus Provider now. Sample template:

```
    {
      "apiVersion": "2014-09-01",
      "name": "[parameters('namespace')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces",
      "location": "[parameters('resourceLacation')]",
      "properties": {
        "messagingSku": "1", //basic tier
        "enabled": true,
        "status": "Active",
        "namespaceType": "Messaging",
        "eventHubEnabled": true,                           
        }         
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for this but is there any way to create queues, topics and subscriptions. Any sample for that ?

Comment: Good example creating Service bus with Queues can be found here:http://wp.sjkp.dk/azure-service-bus-queues-and-sas-with-arm-templates/, one with Topics : https://github.com/sjkp/Azure.ARM.ServiceBus/blob/master/Azure.ARM.ServiceBus/Templates/DeploymentTemplate.json

Comment: Thank you, do you know if it s possible to add sql filter when creating a toppic subscription using ARM ?

Comment: If you can create it via UI (old or new portal) you can then explore it via resources.azure.com and make note of the relevant nodes you need to add

Comment: I've tried this but I can only see the namespace, no node inside

Comment: Here's the docs on using Azure Resource Manager to manage a bus - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-resource-manager-overview/

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a Service Bus Provider yet. The only way you can create / manage Service Bus from a client machine is via [PowerShell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paolos/archive/2014/12/02/how-to-create-a-service-bus-queues-topics-and-subscriptions-using-a-powershell-script.aspx) or through custom code leveraging either an [Azure SDK](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/) or the [REST Management API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh780776.aspx).