# Azure ServiceBus - Queue - Authorization rule creation error

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-resource-manager

I'm creating Azure resource manager template with ServiceBus, queue and couple shared access rules. I'm creating the namespace and the queue correctly but when I try to add authorization rule I get:

> Resource Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/authorizationRules
>   'myservicebusnamespace/SendOnlyKey' failed with message 'Request
>   payload is not in the expected format.

First of all is this possible? There's no samples out there and do documentation either..

Since this is quite generic message I was wondering if anyone else has encountered similar issues using ARM Template for creating Queues?
This is what I have so far:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "sbNamespace": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The service bus namespace"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "sbVersion": "[providers('Microsoft.ServiceBus', 'namespaces').apiVersions[0]]",
    "queueName": "testQueue",
    "defaultSASKeyName": "RootManageSharedAccessKey",
    "authRuleResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/authorizationRules', parameters('sbNamespace'), variables('defaultSASKeyName'))]",
    "sendAuthRuleResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/authorizationRules', parameters('sbNamespace'), 'SendOnlyKey')]",
    "keyGeneratorTemplateUri": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sjkp/Azure.ARM.ServiceBus/master/Azure.ARM.ServiceBus/Templates/keygenerator.json"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
      "name": "primaryKey",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[variables('keyGeneratorTemplateUri')]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "seed": { "value": "1234a5" }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
      "name": "secondaryKey",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[variables('keyGeneratorTemplateUri')]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "seed": { "value": "ac34a5" }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      //namespace
      "apiVersion": "[variables('sbVersion')]",
      "name": "[parameters('sbNamespace')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces",
      "location": "[variables('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "messagingSku": 2
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          //queue
          "apiVersion": "[variables('sbVersion')]",
          "name": "[variables('queueName')]",
          "type": "Queues",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/', parameters('sbNamespace'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "path": "[variables('queueName')]",
            "defaultMessageTimeToLive": "14.0:0:0",
            "maxQueueSizeInMegaBytes": "1024",
            "maxDeliveryCount": "10"
          }
        }
        ,{
          //auth rule 1
          "apiVersion": "[variables('sbVersion')]",
          "name": "[concat(parameters('sbNamespace'),'/SendOnlyKey')]",
          "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/authorizationRules",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/', parameters('sbNamespace'))]",
            "[concat('Microsoft.Resources/deployments/', 'primaryKey')]",
            "[concat('Microsoft.Resources/deployments/', 'secondaryKey')]"
          ],
          "location": "[variables('location')]",
          "properties": {
            "keyName": "SendOnlyKey",
            "PrimaryKey": "[reference('primaryKey').outputs.key.value]",
            "SecondaryKey": "[reference('secondaryKey').outputs.key.value]"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "NamespaceDefaultConnectionString": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[listkeys(variables('authRuleResourceId'), variables('sbVersion')).primaryConnectionString]"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like something is failing with the sub template that should generate the keys.

Could you try to generate they keys with e.g. powershell instead:

```
$bytes = New-Object Byte[] 32
$rand = [System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator]::Create()
$rand.GetBytes($bytes)
$rand.Dispose()
$key = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
```

To see if that fixes the error.

Comment: It could also be the claimType that is wrong. If you are not making a authorizationRule with Send Rights only you should use, claimType: "SharedAccessKey"

Comment: Just had a look at the new file ServiceBusQueues.json in your GitHub repo - looks like what I need, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult stuff, that's for sure. Have a look at

- [Service Bus ARM Templates](http://wp.sjkp.dk/service-bus-arm-templates/)
- [No Service Bus Provider for ARM yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28554098/azure-resource-manager-servicebus-provider)

Comment: I've been using the first link as a source for my investigations. Unfortunately there's not a lot of information out there (I think the ServiceBus provider is in beta at the moment)