# Azure Resource Manager - Add Sql Filter While Creating Service Bus Topic Subscription

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-resource-manager, azure-servicebus-topics

Thanks to this post [azure resource manager servicebus provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28554098/azure-resource-manager-servicebus-provider/34293723),

I was able to provision a servicebus namespace with a topic and a subscription.

I am now wondering if it is possible to add [SQL Filter](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions/#create-a-subscription) while provisioning the subscription ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that someone else asked the same question and got an answer here ^^:

- [Use Azure ARM Template to create Service Bus Topic Subscription with Sql Filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36269935/use-azure-arm-template-to-create-service-bus-topic-subscription-with-sql-filter)